# How do you include all fields from first table in join, and some from remaining?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following:

```
var item = (from table1 in Entity.table1
                            join table2 in Entity.table2
                            on table1.ID equals table2.fkId
                            where table1.ID == TheID
select table1
)
```

How can I return all the fields from `table1`, and then add a few from `table2` without having to explicitly define all the columns again like this:

```
where table1.ID == TheID
   select new
      {
         table1.field,
         table1.field2,
         etc, etc,etc,etc,
         table2.field1

      }
```

Comment: you can't, you need new class that holds both...well maximum that you can do, is to create new {table1, table2} and to access properties mc.table1.field1

Comment: problem is the first class has a huge amount of fields, and I don't want those defined in my code, since it could add maintenance issues later.

Comment: I changed 'results' to 'fields' since they have an entirely different meaning. If this was not a correct edit, could you expand on what you mean with 'results'?

Comment: @Jeroen, yeah thanks, I think you understood it correctly.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it but perhaps you can create a new object that takes two parameters (`dynamic`?). You can then call the constructor in `select new MyObject(table1, table2)` and take the fields of `table2` as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I return all the fields from table1, and then add a few from
>   table2 without having to explicitly define all the columns

You can't. All properties of anonymous object should be specified. But you can return whole instance from table1 and some fields from table2:

```
  select new
  {
     table1
     table2.field1
  }
```

Then all properties from first table will be available via `x.table1.field2` and you would not list them all manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep both table1, and table2 instead

```
where table1.ID == TheID
select new
  {
     table1,
     table2

  }
```

and access to the fields of this anonymous class by by `myItem.table1.field`

If however you want to access by **first-level** properties, you can create [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) class, that returns proper value by reflection from one or another table, or implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to show table on UI(both Winform and WPF grids recognize this interface)